# Problem with STL map iterator copying

Tags: c++, stl, dictionary, iterator

I have an STL map that I want to iterate through, and can't seem to get the code to work. The code is:

```
//PowerupInfo is a struct defined in this class's header file
std::map<std::string, PowerupInfo> powerups;

...populate powerups

std::map<std::string, PowerupInfo>::iterator iter;
for (iter = powerups.begin(); iter != powerups.end(); iter++) {
    return iter->second.type ;
}
```

The error message I get is:

> error: no match for 'operator=' in 'iter = (((const std::map<std::string, PowerupInfo, std::less<std::string>, std::allocator<std::pair<const std::string, PowerupInfo> > >*)((const PowerupList*)this)) + 24u)->std::map<_Key, _Tp, _Compare, _Alloc>::begin with _Key = std::string, _Tp = PowerupInfo, _Compare = std::less<std::string>, _Alloc = std::allocator<std::pair<const std::string, PowerupInfo> >'|
>   note: candidates are: std::_Rb_tree_iterator<std::pair<const std::string, PowerupInfo> >& std::_Rb_tree_iterator<std::pair<const std::string, PowerupInfo> >::operator=(const std::_Rb_tree_iterator<std::pair<const std::string, PowerupInfo> >&)|

So I would normally assume that the problem has to do with setting iter equal to something it doesn't like, as it's not finding a match for 'operator='. But why? Why wouldn't that assignment work?

EDIT:

Turns out the method WAS const, causing the reference to powerups to be const as well, causing the error. I was just doing a bad job reading my own code. Thanks guys!

Comment: Are you sure that `iter = powerups.begin()` instead of `iter = poweruplist.begin()` was your actual intent?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your map name is `poweruplist` not `powerups` (You are using this name in the `for` loop). If this is not the cause of the error, then it looks like you are `for` loop is in a function which accepts the map by const reference (or is a const member function of a class). In that case your type of iterator should be `const_iterator` and not `iterator`.

Comment: you mean you are not getting compiler error now or was it a typo while posting the question?

Comment: Typo while posting the question. powerups is a member of the class Poweruplist, and I got confused  :D

Comment: Changing it to const_iterator fixes the problem, but means I can't change anything pointed to by the iterator, which I do need to do. What's weird though is that as far as I know powerups isn't a const reference. powerups is a private member of the same class this function is a method of. Any ideas?

Comment: Is the member function `const`? or can you post the signature of the method?

Comment: @Lewis, if the function containing this code is declared `const` then any members accessed will also be `const`.

Comment: Your absolutely right, and I was being blind. Turns out the method was const after all, and I was reading the wrong method. Thanks so much!

Answer (score 1):

Reformatting error code to make it readable:

```
error: no match for 'operator=' in 
  'iter = 
    ((
      (const std::map<std::string, PowerupInfo>*)((const PowerupList*)this)
     ) 
      + 24u
    )->std::map<std::string, PowerupInfo>::begin()'
```

Does not look the error message to the code you supplied.
Please cut and past the code. Otherwise it is meaningless.